# keep nodejs server on azure VM running

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I have a Windows Azure VM(linux server 14.04) running and am able to access the VM using command line on my mac/windows machines. I'm running a node.js server and a mongodb instance on this Azure VM.

The problem is that this nodejs server on the VM gets disconnected after sometime(timeout sort of thing). Is it possible that the server on the VM runs indefinitely and keeps serving requests?

PS: My VM is running indefinitely and properly, but the nodejs server on the VM itself times out after sometime. Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Node.js doesn't simply "time out". The issue must be that your app is crashing and doesn't restart. You can run your app with [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) which restarts the application whenever the app crashes. So instead of running your app with `node app.js` you'd run it with `pm2 start app.js`. `npm install -g pm2` to install.

Comment: @Sven thanks for the hint ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Azure VMs will not sleep or shutdown itself , and also will not stop any servers running on them.
And per your description

> the nodejs server on the VM itself times out after sometime

The issue seems the same with what @svenskunganka said.

You can check what occurred the error “sometime”, leveraging PM2 as @Daniel and @svenskunganka suggested.

When you deploy your nodejs project with PM2, it will monitor the application and log errors automatically. You can also monitor your VM metrics (such as CUP Usage,Network in/out) from Azure Portal Monitor panel.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It worked. Does anyone know as to how can the same thing be applied to the mongodb server instance running on the same VM?

Comment: If you meant monitoring mongodb in PM2, maybe you can refer https://github.com/pm2-hive/pm2-mongodb. But I'm not familiar with it, you  can specify your question and open a new thread which is easier for whose experts searching your issue.

Comment: Got it. Had to start the mongodb process as a service, which demonized the process. So, both nodejs server and mongodb server are working indefinitely on the VM. Thanks for the help.  :)

Comment: Totally Agree with @GaryLiu-MSFT but if you are not sure as to what kills your nodejs server, use supervisor to make sure it keeps running even when it crashes out.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably just crashing!

A barebone node application does not get monitored by itself. 
This might sound a little crazy if you come from other web frameworks / platforms like `ASP.NET` or `PHP` where you had `IIS` or `Apache` monitoring your application for you, which was kind of nice tbh. In `node.js` you choose your `process manager` / monitoring system. From my experience, the most popular and well supported `PMs` are the ones listed in the `Expressjs` documentation: http://expressjs.com/advanced/pm.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It worked. Does anyone know as to how can the same thing be applied to the mongodb server instance running on the same VM?